# How i put custom attribute in razor on html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created attribute that check if user connect and I put on funcs in the controller I trying to put it on html to its that possible?

```
@[Allow("RegUser")]     
{                       
    <a href='@Url.Action("Disconnect", "Home")' class="myButtonDis">disconnect</a>
 }
```

Comment: This question makes no sense

Comment: I'm not sure I agree it's not clear what's being asked, just that what's being asked is, er, a bit bonkers.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - No.

Long answer - No - and:

Typically you'd do something more like

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
  @* render conditional here *@
}
```

Or `@if(User.IsInRole("RegUser"))`

Which pre-supposes that whatever login/authentication mechanism you're using is pushing the logged-in user into the HttpContext User.

Beyond this, I can't help much more, because your question is, as the downvotes suggest, really not a good one at all...

Comment: what else can be said, really?

Comment: @jbutler483 :D - however I have attempted to be more helpful

Comment: Andreas: I see that. :P But there does seem to be a rise in questions like these recently. (like, more than usual)

Comment: Agreed - Is there a new "Sam's teach yourself to code in 5 minutes" just been released?